# Telegram bot не рабтает с базой данных

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Telegram bot не работает с базой данных. sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: users.
Вроде бы  все провельно.

````
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("5456447840:AAHM-f1K7_XsmYLJZDiYxV5f9-79MGy_-rg")


@bot.message_handler(command = ['start'])
def start(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id TEXT,
    fname TEXT,
    lname TEXT,
    coin INT);""")
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['join'])
def join(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'input your id')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, idEnter)


def idEnter(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)
    text = message.text
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?""", [text])
    if cursor.fetchall() is None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"This id is not create")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, cursor.fetchone())
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


bot.polling(non_stop=True)```
````

Comment: Проверил SQL запросы, всё работает. Возможно, у Вас где-то проблема в последовательности или подтверждении создания. 
Я бы рекомендовал Вам попробовать вместо постоянных подключений и отключений просто весь код запихнуть в контекстный менеджер with и кроме commit(), Вам больше не придётся каждый раз устанавливать и закрывать подключение. Это хотя бы упростит работу с sql
Пример: with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    Дальше все функции и запросы в нём

Comment: спасиба за советь